# When running cf target I get No org or space targeted, use 'cf.exe target -o ORG -s SPACE'

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am using "Cloud Foundry apps" to deploy my applications to the IBM Cloud. Haven't used this service before.
I am using Windows for converging. I did everything step by step as described on the site.
Logged into my IBM Cloud account and selected the API endpoint.

```
ibmcloud login
```

Targeting Cloud Foundry organization and space:

```
ibmcloud target --cf
```

But in the third step. When needed from the get-start-python directory
submit my app to IBM Cloud
i am getting error when running command:

```
ibmcloud cf push
```

*error*:

```
$ ibmcloud cf push
FAILED
No CF API endpoint set.
Use 'C: \ Users \ ami \ .bluemix \ .cf \ cfcli \ ibmcloud.exe target --cf-api ENDPOINT [-o ORG] [-s SPACE]' to target Cloud Foundry, or 'C: \ Users \ ami \ .bluemix \ .cf \ cfcli \ ibmcloud.exe target --cf 'to target it interactively.
```

Then I decided to look at cf target

```
and I get the inscription:
No org or space targeted, use 'cf.exe target -o ORG -s SPACE'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used `ibmcloud cf target` or `cf target`? Use the one with ibmcloud

Comment: @data_henrik When I use the command: ibmcloud target --cf I see empty ones: "Org" "Space" Next I want to create an ORG ibmcloud cf create-org ORG Writes success! again I use the command: ibmcloud target --cf again I see empty ones: "Org" "Space" I took a screenshot of my steps: https://ibb.co/ZNnf9G3

Comment: Are you on a Lite or paid account? If Lite, what is your home region?

Comment: @data_henrik My account -> Lite region UB London

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are trying to create a Cloud Foundry org in **us-south**, but your home region is **eu-uk**. Per definition of [Lite accounts](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#liteaccount) you can only create one org in one region. That region is your "home" region.

You would need to set the API endpoint to **api.eu-uk.cf.cloud.ibm.com**, set `ibmcloud target -r eu-uk` for the region. Then try again with creating a region or setting the org and space.